# Wildfly clustering with VirtualBox

Tags: cluster-computing, virtualbox, multicast, wildfly, wildfly-8

I am using VirtualBox on a WINDOWS7 as host of two DEBIAN7.7 guests, `deb1` and `deb2`. Each guest can comunicate with the other one. Using one guest browser I can see the Wildfly istance welcome page that's running on the other guest. I run each istance in `standalone-ha` mode, network interfaces have mutlicast enabled, I can see on Wildfly node named `srv1` that the two istances build a cluster:

```
...
...ISPN000094: Received new cluster view: [srv2/web|3] (2) [srv2/web, srv1/web]
```

where `srv1` and `srv2` are the node names of the istances. A tcpdump show UDP packets come across the multicast address 230.0.0.4, just where JGroups is listening. Despite all this goodness, http-session is not shared, this is my problem. 
The application I use is very simple and `<distributable/>`, I have already used it succesfully in a multiple nodes on a single host scenario.

**UPDATE:** I made some tests using jgroups's test application McastReceiverTest and McastSenderTest with the following addresses: 230.0.0.4:45688, 230.0.0.4:45700 and 224.0.1.105:23364. Every test worked, on the receiver guest I can read what I sent by the sender guest. I tried to change my application too, I use this one https://github.com/liweinan/cluster-demo but http session is not shared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wildfly work well, I was looking at the problem as if I was still running multiple istances on my host. As JBoss forum [suggests](https://developer.jboss.org/message/915436), I tried with curl retreiving my JSESSIONID and I see the cluster responding as expected. Happy ending.