# Why can't I replicate the session to other server when I use wildfly?

Tags: java, cluster-computing, wildfly

I have done everything in [WildFly 8 Cluster Howto](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/WildFly+8+Cluster+Howto#WildFly8ClusterHowto-ClusterConfiguration) using domain model. I can see every server in the server manager console, and I can see mod_cluster-manager.

Everything is OK, but when I use the session test war, cluster-demo.war, I visit a server's put.jsp, then close the server, then visit other server's get.jsp, I find that the session is null.

Comment: Are you using your browser to check http session? If it's so try to test with curl instead. I stumble in that trap, maybe it's the same for you. Check my question.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27780952/wildfly-clustering-with-virtualbox

Comment: What are you using for a load balancer?

Comment: Do you see any message in your server console which says something like "session replication has happened" ?

Answer (score 0):

I have done every thing with wildfly 9 document, and failed in the last step http://IP/cluster-mode/put.jsp.

I solve the question with follow steps:(OS is Cent 6.5)

1. I use mod_cluster with 1.2.6 version.
2. Add "EnableMCPMReceive ON" in httpd.conf:`<VirtualHost IP:10001>` tag.
3. Modify **Slave** domain.xml, search the "CHANGE ME !!" in `<hornetq-server>` tag, and change it to "@password@".
4. Modify Master and Slave domain.xml 
   From

   `<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:modcluster:2.0">
    <mod-cluster-config advertise-socket="modcluster" connector="ajp">
      <dynamic-load-provider>
       <load-metric type="???"/>(I forgot original setting)
      </dynamic-load-provider>
    </mod-cluster-config>
   </subsystem>`

TO

```
`<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:modcluster:2.0">
 <mod-cluster-config advertise-socket="modcluster" connector="ajp" proxy-list="IP:10001" balancer="other_server_group">
   <dynamic-load-provider>
    <load-metric type="busyness"/>
   </dynamic-load-provider>
 </mod-cluster-config>
</subsystem>`
```

PS: the balancer value must mapping httpd.conf:"ManagerBalancerName" setting and can't use "-".

5. Stop iptables whit command : sudo service iptables stop
6. Stop SELinux with command : sudo setenforce 0
7. restart httpd, JBoass master ,slave.

All you done will see http://IP/cluster-mode/put.jsp have time to show.

Hope this can help you.